# is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [com]

Tags: tomcat, jakarta-ee

Hello every one i am coming to the point directly

i configured  my server.xml like this

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <Resource name="jdbc/MCDataSource"
              global="jdbc/MCDataSource"
              auth="Container"
              type="javax.sql.DataSource"
              username="AppDB"
              password="AppDB"
              url="jdbc:oracle:thin:@172.19.8.159:1521/OIM.itba.gov.in"
              driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver"
              initialSize="20"
              maxWaitMillis="15000"
              maxTotal="75"
              maxIdle="20"
              maxAge="7200000"
              testOnBorrow="true"
              validationQuery="select 1"
              />   
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

and i configured my context.xml like this

```
<Context>

    <!-- Default set of monitored resources -->
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>

     <ResourceLink name="jdbc/MCDataSource"
                global="jdbc/MCDataSource"
                auth="Container"
                type="javax.sql.DataSource" />

</Context>
```

and my web.xml

```
    <resource-ref>
    <description>DB Connection</description>
    <res-ref-name>jdbc/MCDataSource</res-ref-name>
    <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
    <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
</resource-ref>
```

here is my code to get the connection.

```
DataSource dataSource=null;
        try {
            Context initContext=new InitialContext();
            Context context= (Context)initContext.lookup("java:/comp/env");
            dataSource=(DataSource)context.lookup("jdbc/MCDataSource");
        Connection  connection=dataSource.getConnection();

        } catch (NamingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

while calling this code i am getting above exception 
here is my exception stack trace

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Name [com/env/jdbc/MCDataSource] is not bound in this Context. Unable to find [com].
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:819)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:167)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:156)
    at javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:392)
    at com.tcs.controller.BpmController.run(BpmController.java:56)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
```

can any body please tell me what am i doing wrong here.

Comment: Are you still having problems? It's really odd because in the console output the context is `com/env/jdbc/MCDataSource` while the code specifies `comp/env/jdbc/MCDataSource`. Are you that it's this part of the code that caused the problem?

Comment: thanks for your reply.. later i moved my code to weblogic server and i did the configuration according to that and everything has been working fine.. but please tell me why it is happening and what is the solution for this.